# Decode and Show Image Thumbnail in MessageBox Android Activity Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-realtime-database

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-real-time-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial.html#comment-44484). With this link you can see my comment for the particular problem, I followed this tutorial and I was at success to send and receive text messages on both peers. I can also see my Firebase database from console and its updating as well. Thing working fine till here.

Now, I want to send/receive camera images to Firebase, so I found various methods to convert a image to Base64 encode string, upload that string to Firebase database, I am success at this also.

I have successfully uploaded the encoded string to Firebase. Now as my current system is build for only text string messages application got crash when it receives encode string .

1. How to decode encoded string back to bitmap?
2. Show bitmap image thumbnail in MessageBox

Here is my modified chat.java activity code: as a reference you can follow the provided url up for chat.java class and how it works originally, but I am unable to achieve decoding and showing bitmap thumbnail in messagebox.

**chat.java**

```
public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout layout;
    ImageView sendButton,vidcall,cam;
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "";
    EditText messageArea;
    ScrollView scrollView;
    Firebase reference1, reference2;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    String urltok;
    public static String msg;
    String tuk;
    private Uri selectedImage = null;
    private Bitmap bitmap, bitmapRotate;
    String imagepath = "";String fname;
    File file;
    private Boolean upflag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_chat);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(Chat.this);

        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        sendButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        vidcall = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vidBtnk);
        messageArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageArea);
        scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        cam = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pictk);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        reference1 = new Firebase("https://*******.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
        reference2 = new Firebase("https://*******.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.chatWith + "_" + UserDetails.username);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
                msg = messageText;

                if(!messageText.equals("")){
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("message", messageText);
                    map.put("user", UserDetails.username);
                    reference1.push().setValue(map);
                    reference2.push().setValue(map);
              }

                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                messageArea.setText("");

            }
        });

        vidcall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Chat.this, ConnectActivity.class));
            }
        });


       cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraintent, 101);
            }
        });

        reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String message = map.get("message").toString();
                String userName = map.get("user").toString();

                if(userName.equals(UserDetails.username)){
                    addMessageBox("You:-\n" + message, 1);
                   // addimagethumb(bitmapRotate,1);
                }
                else{
                    addMessageBox(UserDetails.chatWith + ":-\n" + message, 2);
                   // addimagethumb(bitmapRotate,2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    } //oncreate ends


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 101:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            selectedImage = data.getData(); // the uri of the image taken
                            if (String.valueOf((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")).equals("null")) {
                                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                                } else {
                                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                                }
                            if (Float.valueOf(getImageOrientation()) >= 0) {
                                bitmapRotate = rotateImage(bitmap, Float.valueOf(getImageOrientation()));
                                } else {
                                bitmapRotate = bitmap;
                                bitmap.recycle();
                                }

                           // ivImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapRotate);

//                            Saving image to mobile internal memory for sometime
                            //String root = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();

                            String root = "/storage/emulated/0";

                            File myDir = new File(root + "/hidoctor");
                            myDir.mkdirs();

                            Random generator = new Random();
                            int n = 10000;
                            n = generator.nextInt(n);

//                            Give the file name that u want
                            fname = "null" + n + ".jpg";

                            imagepath = root + "/hidoctor/" + fname;
                            file = new File(myDir, fname);
                            upflag = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        if (!upflag) {
        Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Image Not Captured..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
        saveFile(bitmapRotate, file);
        encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(bitmapRotate);
        }
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "No Internet Connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        reference1.child("imageUrl").push().setValue(imageEncoded);
        reference2.child("imageUrl").push().setValue(imageEncoded);
     }

     private int getImageOrientation() {
     final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
     System.out.println("orientation===" + orientation);
    cursor.close();
     return orientation;
   } else {
    return 0;
    }
  }


    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Bitmap retVal;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    retVal = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return retVal;
    }

    // Saving file to the mobile internal memory
    private void saveFile(Bitmap sourceUri, File destination) {
    if (destination.exists()) destination.delete();
   try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    sourceUri.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
    //new DoFileUpload().execute();
    } else {
    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "No Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public void addimagethumb(Bitmap pic , int type){
              ImageView imgpresc = new ImageView(Chat.this);
              imgpresc.setImageBitmap(pic);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
              imgpresc.setLayoutParams(lp);

              if(type == 1) {
                 // textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
              }
              else{
                 // textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner2);
              }

              layout.addView(imgpresc);
              scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

    public void addMessageBox(String message, int type){
        TextView textView = new TextView(Chat.this);
        //ImageView imgpresc = new ImageView(Chat.this);
        textView.setText(message);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        if(type == 1) {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
        }
        else{
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner2);
        }

        layout.addView(textView);
        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }



 }
```

So Far I am getting this :

[image]

Now when we tap cam icon on appbar it goes to camera takes the picture and on return it saves image to device storage and encode&upload to firebase after this iwant both users to see like this image

**I Want like this**

[image]

If you check my chat.java activity class I tried to add imageview dynamically to view but when user encode and upload the picture once and when on next session upon oncreate the activity crashed for null value . system gets confuse when retrieving the message from map for user . and all the references got lost .

Kindly help me , I am stuck on this for more than 30 days . It will be much appreciated . Thanks

Comment: There's a firebase storage option for this purpose . Use it

Comment: the problem is not with Storage , I can encode and decode image bitmap strings . the problem is at client side , after storing showing the thumbnail in messagebox , app gets crash because my way disturbs the referencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a separate child for images and wverything worked fine

```
imagref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map map2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String retrieveEncodedImg = map2.get("imageUrl").toString();

                Log.e("encodedimagegetmap2", retrieveEncodedImg+"");

                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(retrieveEncodedImg, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                     addimagethumb(decodedByte,1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Here you can check my output

[image]